# How Array.prototype.sort() is Implemented?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays, sorting

I implemented a filter in angular to sort an array of objects. I used [Array.prototype.sort()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) to implement that and was able to complete the task sucessfully.

Now i'm trying to optimize the filter that i have implemented and need to know how the Array.prototype.sort() is implemented and what is the algorithm it uses for sorting.

Comment: You can't optimise it. It's already optimised. There is no standard for how `sort` is implemented as long as the contract is fulfilled. One browser may use quicksort, another may be using mergesort. Chrome, for example, actually does different sorts depending on the size of the array - for small ones, it uses one, for larger ones - another.

Comment: I need to optimize the filter that i implemented. I edited the question. And i found the answers in the original post.I has the answers i need.

Comment: The answers are old and the implementation might have changed. The implementation can also change in the future.

Comment: Question is pretty old as well as some answers. There are some answers which were posted recently. It is better if there is an official documentation which i can refer to.